# Is possible to map the design automation API result data to the viewer API objects by objectId?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

Using Design automation API, I am extracting the data from 2d DWG file.
Extracted data contains circles, lines, polylines and so.

Question: Objects in viewer API and data extracted from design API for the same 2d DWG file.  So, can we able to identify those objects from both APIs by its object ID's?
or is there any way to map viewer API object with design API output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use object handles to uniquely identify objects in the viewer and design automation. It sounds like what you want to do is extract some data from the dwg using design automation and then show this data in the viewer. We have a sample that does this: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer
This sample actually shows how to generate viewer data on design automation too (thus avoiding having to process the dwg twice).

Comment: Hi Albert, Thanks for the link. From that link, I have concluded that external Id(or element id)  from viewer API object properties and the ID's returned from obj.Handle.ToString() in Autodesk .net API(Desing automation API) is always same. Is that right?